# Как правильно расположить кнопку поверх input не ломая верстку

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Я верстаю небольшой сайт для себя, в данный момент - форму регистрации. У меня возникла проблема с размещением глаза (который скрывает и показывает пароль)

[image: форма регистрации]

Глаз должен быть поверх `input-а`, но я не понимаю, как это сделать без использования абсолюта. Подскажите, пожалуйста. Желательно, чтобы способ был универсален для всех устройств.

Comment: А почему абсолют - не то?

Comment: Сделайте ему отрицательный левый маргин с его размер (-30px).

Comment: Если я делаю через абсолют, то на всех устройствах по разному выглядит

Comment: Про маргин помогло, большое спасибо

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/ExWpeOJ - вроде так ?

Comment: На всех сайтах используют внутри инпута а не снаружи

Comment: @Proskima в чем заключается отличие отображения при размещении абсолютом? можете показать пример кода